# SIMBL Plugins not launching properly under OS X Lion

Tags: finder, safari, plugins

I have OS X Lion installed on my 2011 MacBook Pro. I also have [SIMBL](http://www.culater.net/software/SIMBL/SIMBL.php) with two plugins: [Colorful Sidebar](http://cooviewerzoom.web.fc2.com/colorfulsidebar.html) and [Safari Omnibar](http://hackemist.com/SafariOmnibar/#about). I (obviously) have Finder launch when I login, and I also have Safari launch at login.

My issue is that when I first use either application, the desired effect of the application does not kick in. i.e. the icons in Finder's sidebar are still gray, and the google search box can still be found as a separate entity in safari.

Restarting either application causes the SIMBL plugin to kick in for that application.

My question is why are these plugins not activating and doing what they are supposed to do until after I relaunch their respective application?

Comment: By any chance when you shutdown or log off, are you leaving the option to "reopen windows when logging back in" enabled? Because I suspect that may be the culprit, though that wouldn't really explain Finder. It may simply be a limitation of the SIMBL plugin.

Comment: I am using the same SIMBL plugins as you.  However, Safari Ominbar is working properly for me, while ColorFful sidebar is not working properly unless I kill the Finder.  So, ask the same question with u.

Comment: @cksum AFAICT, it doesn't matter whether or not I leave the box checked or not.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this is the behaviour of the SIMBL plugin.

> One oddity about this solution is that you may need to kill the Finder
>   again to bring the color icons back after a full system reboot

[Source](http://osxdaily.com/2011/08/25/get-color-sidebar-icons-back-in-mac-os-x-10-7-lion-finder-windows/)

Comment: The Applescript I have does that for you.  It is launched at EVERY login, but after the Finder is up and running.  I even catch it in my Dock momentarily if I happen to be alert. I'm going to search again to provide a link for the script.

Answer (score 1):

On the Omnibar page's FAQ they say that it is known issue and it is suggested to reinstall Omnibar since newer versions are shipped with patched SIMBL.
See the third question from the bottom of [this page](http://hackemist.com/SafariOmnibar/#tab-faq).

Answer (score 0):

The plugins will not activate by themselves. They activate when the app is launched, as an intended accessory to the app.

I do not know what to do about Safari Omnibar, but I have an Applescript someone compiled that runs on login.  It  shuts down the Finder and relaunches it immediately after the Finder is active at startup, giving me thee Colorful Finder window.

I would imagine that the Applescript could be modified to do the sam for Safari Omnibar, but I am not a scripter.

I just searched for the source of this script to provide the link, but failed.  Being new here, I don't know the protocol about sharing this script, as it is essentially a hack.

Comment: Well, on start-up of the computer, the apps are launching, so the expected behavior, at least as far as I can tell is for the SIMBL plugins to kick in. Unless I'm missing something.

Answer (score -1):

Here you can find the answers

http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20110825114202681

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! Answers on Ask Different should be more than just a link. Please edit your answer to in clued the relevant information from the linked article.